# How can assembler initialize variables which contain other variable address in position independent?

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, x86-64

### Code Example

```
.section .data
  arg0: .asciz "/bin/bash"
  arg1: .asciz "-c"
  arg2: .asciz "ls v* && echo hello"

  # How come these argv values initialized?
  argv: .quad arg0, arg1, arg2, 0

.section .text
.global _start

_start:
  xorl  %edx, %edx
  leaq  arg0(%rip), %rdi
  leaq  argv(%rip), %rsi
  movl  $59, %eax
  syscall
```

In that example, we can say that `argv` is an array of pointers that contains `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2` and `NULL` (they are all just a pointer).

But when it is compiled as position independent code/executable, the addresses correspond to `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2` are not known at compile time.

How come the assembler initialize `argv` values so that they are loaded correctly at runtime?

Comment: Linux dynamic linking for shared objects supports runtime fixups, aka "relocations".  (Even in the read-only `.text` section, but .data is already read+write so it's not even weird to let it get modified.)

Comment: You are absolute right: As Peter Cordes already mentioned, your piece of code **will** contain relocations. This means that the code is **not** "really" position-independent but the pointer variables must be "updated" (e.g. by the operating system) before the code is started. I doubt that it is possible to initialize a pointer variable in x86 code in a way that the result is "really" position independent.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: You could of course init it at run-time with store instructions (after a RIP-relative LEA).  But yeah, by definition a pointer variable is an absolute address, and there's no way to have the right absolute address sitting in the file on disk for a relocatable executable / shared object.  GCC `-fPIC` will construct jump tables that use relative offsets instead of absolute addresses, but that's not an option here because you actually need an array of absolute addresses as an arg for a syscall.

Comment: @PeterCordes I explicitly mentioned the "x86" because there *might* be calling conventions for other CPUs where pointer variables don't contain absolute addresses but addresses which are - for example - relative to some label in the code... Using such calling conventions you could initialize pointer variables and the code is really position-independent.

Comment: PIC in general relies on a table, a global offset table, that is built to be fixed in place relative to either the start of .data or if read only relative to the code (the code being built to be position independent itself and can live almost anywhere without issue).   so there is a table in a known location, and in that table contains the dynamic list.   so say argc is entry 3 in the table you address to the table plus 3 entries and then use that address vs just having the address, so it is a level of indirection.  simply disassembling an fPIC built test program will show this

Comment: argc, argv, etc specifically might be passed in in registers and in that case the caller takes care of this and not the function itself.

Comment: when you say compile time do you include linking as well as depending on the architecture and the tools the linker can modify code created by the compiler.  so examine both when you do your examples the compiler output and the linker output.